# Using the cell value in Name Manager formula as reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to create a formula in Name Manager using the reference of other sheet.
I have two sheet A1 and A2; in sheet A2 i have sample data.
Using this sample data i want to create a list which will be used in sheet A1 depending on other Drop-down value.
I want to create a name for formula:

```
=A2!$C$10:$C$12
```

But in this formula i want to change column number 10 and 12 with another cell (in same sheet A2) values.
Like: `=CELL("contents",E6)`.

I have tried:
 `=A2!$C$CELL("contents",E6):$C$CELL("contents",F6)`
But its not working.

How can i change the column numbers with other cell values?

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you try to define a name using the following formula?

```
=OFFSET('A2'!$C$1,'A2'!$E$6-1,0,'A2'!$F$6-'A2'!$E$6+1,1)
```

This will define a range which is one column wide (`C` column), starts at row number found in cell `E6` and end at row number found in cell `F6`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
=INDIRECT("A2!$C$"&E6&":$C$"&F6)
```

Please take note that you can, and maybe should, add sheet reference to cells E6 and F6.